# How to search for Debian CLI packages?

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management, gui, nano

I recently installed Debian for CLI purposes.
I am looking to install CLI packages, I want to know how to search for packages (CLI packages such as nano)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find CLI packages in Debian, you can look for packages tagged as `interface::command-line`, either [using the tag search engine](https://debtags.debian.org/search/?wl=interface%3A%3Acommandline&q=&qf=default), or on your system by installing `debtags` and running

```
debtags search interface::command-line
```

Both approaches have options to refine the search. See [the Debtags wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/Debtags) for more details.

This does have limits: packages aren’t all tagged appropriately. You can also look for packages which depend on `libncurses6`:

```
apt-rdepends -r libncurses6
```

Answer (score 5):

When installing Debian, you have the option of installing no desktop-environment.  That will leave you with a CLI-only (headless) machine.  If you installed a desktop-environment during that step, you will need to uninstall the desktop environment.  `sudo apt purge gnome` may be sufficient.

Once the machine is headless, `sudo apt install` whatever you like to arm the installation, but avoid the `-y` to ensure you are prompted before actually installing anything. Review `The following NEW packages will be installed:` before continuing.  If it includes packages like `adwaita-icon-theme` or `x11-common`, then you know this is not a headless package and you should abort the installation.

Stephen's answer is a more direct answer to how to search for CLI packages, but I thought it was worth answering "how can I know that specific package is CLI" without relying on debtags.

Comment: Under Debian, one can also run [`sudo tasksel`](https://wiki.debian.org/tasksel) to deselect the desktop environment, which will be effectively the same as removing `task-desktop` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the executable name (e.g. `nano`, as mentioned in the question), you can use `apt-file` to search for specific executable file in all available packages.

```
# apt-file search bin/nano
mocha: /usr/share/nodejs/mocha/node_modules/nanoid/bin/nanoid.cjs
mocha: /usr/share/nodejs/mocha/node_modules/nanoid/bin/nanoid.test.js
nano: /bin/nano
nano-tiny: /bin/nano-tiny
nanoc: /usr/bin/nanoc
...
```

There may be false positives, but it is useful to find some packages where you know specific command, but don't know the package name.

`apt-file` itself requires installation and it needs to download database of filenames.

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP already knows package names and want to find a way to tell whether `nano` is CLI or GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You could prevent GUI packages from being installed, e.g. by putting the client-side X11 library on hold with

```
sudo apt-mark hold libx11-6
```

or by pinning this package via `/etc/apt/preferences`

```
Package: libx11-6
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

At this point, installation of GUI packages should be impossible, so any package you manage to install will be CLI. Try installing the packages you need: if they are all CLI, you'll just get them installed, if not, you'll get a list of non-CLI packages for which you need to find an alternative.

This will not give you a list of all CLI packages, but I'm not sure how useful such a list will actually be, unless you want to install every single one of them.

Comment: It might be worth adding `libwayland-client0` as well. However excluding `libx11-6` will also exclude programs which support running with or without X, for example Emacs; for Emacs this isn’t a blocker (there’s an `emacs-nox` package), but there may be other which are artificially excluded.

Answer (score 1):

To search for a package on the cli I usually

```
apt-cache search 'name'
```

This returns a list with all packages with 'name' in the description
To get a detailed view of the package run

```
apt-cache show 'name'
```

Comment: He doesn't say he wants to search using the CLI, he says he wants the search to return packages with only CLI softwares.